# How to use JSImport when writing scalajs facade for javascript modules

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-bundler

I have written a facade using JSImport, and it works.  Unfortunately, I arrived at the solution through trial and error, and I don't fully understand why this particular solution works but others I tried did not.

Background: I'm starting with a working project, built with sbt, which is a single page application that implements the client side code with scala.js and the server side with scala and the Play framework.  The javascript libraries were packaged with web jars and bundled into the client js file using the sbt jsDependencies variable.  I wanted to implement some new features which required a library up rev, which then required an up rev of some javascript libs which were only available in npm format.  So now I am including all the javascript dependencies for the client app using npmDependencies with the scalajs-bundler plugin.  This broke some of the scalajs facades leading to my question.

I'll use the facade to [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/docs/manual.html#jsonlayout) as an example for this question.

The variable `log4javascript` is the top level object used to access the rest of the api.

When the js libs were included as web jars, this is how the facade to `log4javascript` was implemented:

```scala
@js.native
@js.annotation.JSGlobalScope
object Log4JavaScript extends js.Object {
  val log4javascript:Log4JavaScript = js.native
}
```

After the change to npm:

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSImport.Namespace

@JSImport("log4javascript", Namespace)
@js.native
object Log4JavaScript extends js.Object {
  def resetConfiguration(): Unit = js.native
  def getLogger(name:js.UndefOr[String]): JSLogger = js.native
  ...
}
```

Following the scala.js [docs](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html) for writing importing modules I expected the object name (Log4JavaScript in this case) would have to match the exported symbol name in order for the binding to work.  However, the top level symbol in log4javascript.js is `log4javascript`.  After experimenting, it seems the scala object name makes no difference for the binding.  It binds correctly no matter what I name the scala top level object.

Can someone explain what relationship exists, if any, between the scala object/class/def/val names and the names in the javascript module when using the 'Namespace' arg to JSImport?

According to the scala.js docs, it seems I should be able to provide the actual name of the js object (I also tried "Log4JavaScript")

```scala
@JSImport("log4javascript", "log4javascript")
@js.native
object SomeOtherName extends js.Object {
  def resetConfiguration(): Unit = js.native
  def getLogger(name:js.UndefOr[String]): JSLogger = js.native
  ...
}
```

However, this fails to bind. I will get a runtime error when I try to access any of the member functions.

`Log4JavaScript.resetConfiguration()`

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resetConfiguration' of undefined`

Can someone explain why this doesn't work?

log4javascript also defines some classes inside the scope of `log4javascript`.  When the lib was included as a web jar the definition looked like:

```scala
@js.native
@JSGlobal("log4javascript.AjaxAppender")
class AjaxAppender(url:String) extends Appender {
  def addHeader(header:String, value:String):Unit = js.native
}
```

After switching to npm I had to put the class definition inside the top level object:

```scala
@js.native
trait Appender extends js.Object {
  ...
}

@JSImport("log4javascript", "log4javascript")
@js.native
object Log4JavaScript extends js.Object {
  ...
  class AjaxAppender(url: String) extends Appender {
    def addHeader(name: String, value: String): Unit = js.native 
  }
  ...
}
```

This seems sensible, but from the scala.js docs it seems like it should have been possible to define it this way outside of the top level object

```scala
@JSImport("log4javascript", "log4javascript.AjaxAppender")
@js.native
class AjaxAppender(url: String) extends Appender {
  def addHeader(name: String, value: String): Unit = js.native 
}
```

However, this also fails to bind.  Could someone explain the correct way to define the class as above?  Or is the definition nested inside the `Log4JavaScript` object the only correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain what relationship exists, if any, between the scala object/class/def/val names and the names in the javascript module when using the 'Namespace' arg to JSImport?

This is explained in [this part](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html#-imports-from-other-javascript-modules) of the Scala.js documentation. The name of the Scala object defining the facade does not matter. What matter are the parameters of the `@JSImport` annotation. The first one indicates *which* module to import from, and the second one indicates *what* to import.

In your case, the log4javascript module is in the `log4javascript.js` file, in the `log4javascript` package directory. So, your first parameter should be:

```scala
@JSImport("log4javascript/log4javascript.js", ...)
object Log4JavaScript ...
```

However, log4javascript is defined as an npm module whose [main file](https://github.com/Ritzlgrmft/log4javascript/blob/8aade2bcfe4302058aa25a111890b129995d4c6b/package.json#L10) refers to the `log4javascript.js` file. This means that you can just use the package directory name:

```scala
@JSImport("log4javascript", ...)
object Log4JavaScript ...
```

(See [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8/) for more information on how NodeJS does resolve modules)

The second parameter of the `@JSImport` annotation indicates what to import. In your case, you want to import the whole module, not just a member of it, so you want to use `Namespace`:

```scala
@JSImport("log4javascript", Namespace)
object Log4JavaScript ...
```

This corresponds to the following EcmaScript import statement:

```js
import * as Log4JavaScript from 'log4javascript'
```

Note that, although the Scala object name (`Log4JavaScript`, here) does not matter, the names of its members *does matter*, as explained in [this part](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html#javascript-fieldmethod-names-and-their-scala-counterpart) of the Scala.js documentation.

> According to the scala.js docs, it seems I should be able to provide the actual name of the js object (I also tried "Log4JavaScript")
>
> ```scala
> @JSImport("log4javascript", "log4javascript")
> ...
> ```
>
> However, this fails to bind. I will get a runtime error when I try to access any of the member functions.

When you write that, you try to access to the `log4javascript` member of the `log4javascript` module. But that module does not have such a member.

> it should have been possible to define it this way outside of the top level object
>
> ```scala
> @JSImport("log4javascript", "log4javascript.AjaxAppender")
> ...
> ```
>
> However, this also fails to bind.

Again, this means “import the `log4javascript.AjaxAppender` member from the `log4javascript` module”, but that module does not have such a member. The following should work:

```scala
@JSImport("log4javascript", "AjaxAppender")
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a bit clearer than the scala.js docs.  How did you determine the structure of the log4javascript package?  Is there a tool to browse the package structure (I've searched for that, but could not find it)?  Or do you just have to download and extract the package locally to browse the package directory in the file system?  I've found that most of the json lib docs don't describe the module structure and api in the kind of detail necessary to write a scalajs facade.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no general rule. Most of the time the documentation of the JavaScript module explains how it should be used. However, in the case of log4javascript, I’ve noticed that the documentation does not explain how to use it as an NPM module…